# ASP.NET MVC Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC website, and it is running on IIS6. Since i have not access to the webserver, i use the .aspx extension (in global.asax). I have a controller called "Quiz" and all of their methods marked with an authAttribute. When the user is not authorized, it should redirect to "/Account.aspx/Logon?ReturnUrl=Test.aspx", but i get a wrong url: "/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=Test.aspx". How can i fix this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Account.aspx/Login" />
</authentication>
```